# GridView having 1 ImageView per row in portratit and 2 ImageViews in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, landscape-portrait

I actually have a ListActivity fed by a custom ArrayAdapter. It builds rows made by single ImageViews. In portrait mode it looks nice. But in landscape mode it stretches the image to the borders (I set scaleType to fitXY).
I would like to have 2 ImageViews per row in landscape mode. Is GridView the right layout?
How would you do this?

Since I have a 480x800 screen, in portrait, the ImageView would be 480px wide, while in landscape each of the two would be 400px wide. This is not a problem, but it is important to me to respect the width/height ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use Gridview to do your task. If you want to use listview you have to check for the orientation, based on the orientations

1) In landscape mode the layout from the layout-land/ will be loaded which contains the 2 imageviews.

2) In portrait mode the layout from the layout-port/ will be loaded which contains the 1 imageview.

Comment: how can you use listview and have 2 views per row?

Comment: the layout will have 2 views where in getView() method you have to set 2 images in landscape mode.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `GridView` is the best and easiest approach. You can use the same custom `ArrayAdapter` and `OnClickListener` you have now for the `ListView`, and only need to change

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
GridView myGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

and the xml to something like:

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="390px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Now, you should avoid using "px" as units and use "dp" instead, and that only if you are really sure your app is designed only for a 480x800 resolution.

Answer (score 1):

gridView is not much of a layout . it's an adapterView , so its purpose is to be able to "show" tons of views and also be able to scroll between them .

maybe you would like to use gridLayout instead ? it also has a comparability library ...

anyway , if you wish to stick with gridView , simply set the `android:numColumns` to be of a variable that you set via the values folder for portrait mode , and and values-land for the value you need for landscape

---

EDIT: here's the solution of using a gridView :

the layout xml file should contain something like:

```
<GridView android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:numColumns="@integer/cols" android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
```

create an xml file (for example "consts.xml") in the `res/values` folder that has something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item type="integer" name="cols">2</item>
</resources>
```

also , create the same file in `res/values-land` folder , and set the 2 to be 3 .

Comment: And how would you add the adapter to the GridLayout?

Comment: gridLayout is not an adapterView , so it can't get an adapter. you could , of course extend it and add this feature . of course , you can simply put the value for the columns to be different on the values-land as i've suggested , for the gridView solution .

Comment: anyway , see my updated answer . for monitoring onClick events, use the gridView and call "setOnItemClickListener" , as shown in the API : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) . also , in order to keep the aspect ratio of the imageView , don't set the image via the background , and set adjustViewBounds to true .

Answer (score 1):

You can supply different resources for different orientations. So, when the device is in landscape, you populate the `ListView` with a layout that has two `ImageView`s in every item and in portrait, the layout has 1 `ImageView` per item.

Take a look at [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) to know about how you can provide different layout XMLs for different orientations.

Sample code:

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener mImageListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the ImageView is clicked
    }
};

//Check the orientation and handle accordingly in the getView
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent);
    }
    ImageView leftImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.leftImage);
    ImageView rightImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightImage);
    boolean isTwoColumn = (rightImage != null);

    //If it is two column layout, set both ImageViews
    if(isTwoColumn){
      leftImage.setImageResource(...);
      leftImage.setOnClickListener(mImageListener);
      rightImage.setImageResource(...);
      rightImage.setOnClickListener(mImageListener);
    }else{
      leftImage.setImageResource(...);
      leftImage.setOnClickListener(mImageListener);
    }
}
```

/res/layout-land/list-item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
      android:id="+@id/leftImage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
      android:id="+@id/rightImage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

/res/layout-port/list-item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
      android:id="+@id/leftImage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This would be good. But then when I override "getView" I need to return a LinearLayout with two ImageViews in landscape, and a simple ImageView in portrait. Thus getView needs to know which display orientation is being used and to access two items in the array when needed. Is this feasible?

Comment: Yes. You can take a look at the Honeycomb Gallery sample to know how to identify the orientation. Briefly, you can check whether the `View` returned by `findViewById` is `null` or not and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Careful though, if you need to set an action onClick for each image, it'll not be easy at all to implement that using a ListView.

Comment: @Adinia that's exactly what I was thinking... I actually need to use onClick. I would not be able to distinguish which "column" was clicked. Only the row...

Comment: Every individual `View` on a `ListView` item can respond to touch events. I do not see any reason why you will have problem with `onClick`.

Comment: @Rajesh When a Listview row will hold 2 images, it'll not be easy to set different onClick action for each of them.

Comment: @Adinia - Why do you think it will not be easy? and why do you need different onClick listeners? Even if you want different onClick listeners, you can easily provide anonymous objects as is done with any kind event handling.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the code for that to prove it's that easy :) ; I really can't see why you'd want to override the simple ListView onClick listener to differentiate between a click on the right half and the left half of the n-th row. To not talk about the pain to feed such a list...

Comment: Added sample code to illustrate how to handle events. Please tell me the where do you find it painful or difficult

Answer (score 0):

I tried Gridview and personally found it was incredibly fiddly to get the display I was after (which was ratio correct display for smaller cells inside)... after weeks of restling with it on different resolutions and screen formats I opted for creating my own gridview from scratch and haven't looked back.

I'm not saying Gridview isn't without it's merit but what I can say is to implement your own system takes a matter of hours if you have a very clear idea in your mind how it should operate you'll probably find it easier to code your own.

In essence it was just a class derived from ViewGroup, override the onMeasure and onLayout items to measure the child views it contains and next lay them out into the locations on screen that you want them.

If you're looking for long lists however I'd still look at the listview or perhaps gridview might be worth a shot but this is certainly good peace of mind to know you can take control of it all if you need to.